# Text box minimum length validation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Total counts 100. After I entered 101 letter show alerts or error message it is not working in this code.

Html

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtarea" runat="server" Width="700px" Height="80px" TextMode="MultiLine"
    onkeyup="cnt(this)" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox>
<p style="text-align: right;">
    <asp:Label ID="lblcharcnt" runat="server" Text="100"></asp:Label>
</p>
<asp:Label ID="lblcount" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("row") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cnt(text) {
        var a = text.value;
        var b = "character left.";
        text.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = 100 - a.length + " " + b;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: pure jquery https://jsfiddle.net/umynof8b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I use for this purpose. Note the use of `<%= 1000 - TextBox1.Text.Length %>`. This will make sure the correct remaining characters are displayed after PostBack or setting an initial value.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" onKeyUp="setMaxLength(this)" isMaxLength="1000" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>

<span id="<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>_remain"><%= 1000 - TextBox1.Text.Length %></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function setMaxLength(control) {
        //get the isMaxLength attribute
        var mLength = control.getAttribute ? parseInt(control.getAttribute("isMaxLength")) : ""

        //was the attribute found and the length is more than the max then trim it
        if (control.getAttribute && control.value.length > mLength) {
            control.value = control.value.substring(0, mLength);
            alert('Length exceeded');
        }

        //display the remaining characters
        var modid = control.getAttribute("id") + "_remain";
        if (document.getElementById(modid) != null) {
            document.getElementById(modid).innerHTML = mLength - control.value.length;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Sir @VDWWD

Answer (score 2):

Did changes in javascript. Try it and let me know if further help require.

```
function cnt(text) {
        var a = text.value;
        var b = "character left.";
        if (a.length > 100) {
            alert('length grater than 100.');
        } else {
            text.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = 100 - a.length + " " + b;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Sir @InnovaITve Solutions

Answer (score 1):

This will show a popup if you eneter more than 100 characters in textbox
ASP.Net

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQ1F0" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="2" Columns="35" onKeyUp="javascript:Count(this);" onChange="javascript:Count(this);" />
```

javascript

```
 function Count(text) {
        var maxlength = 100; //set your value here 
        var object = document.getElementById(text.id)  
        if (object.value.length > maxlength) {
            object.focus(); //set focus to prevent jumping
            var count1=object.value.length;
            alert('You have exceeded the comment length of 100 characters , total characters entered are : '+count1);
            object.value = text.value.substring(0, maxlength); //truncate the value
            object.scrollTop = object.scrollHeight; //scroll to the end to prevent jumping
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: @IvinRaj , if it answer your question than please mark it as answer

Answer (score 1):

I have rewritten JavaScript function like below. Now, User can not enter post maximum length. User will be restricted to enter only 100 characters

```
     function multilineTextBoxKeyDown(textBox, e, maxLength) {
        var selectedText = textBox.value;
        var b = "character left.";
        if (!checkSpecialKeys(e)) {
            var length = parseInt(maxLength);
            if (textBox.value.length > length) {
                textBox.value = textBox.value.substring(0, maxLength);
                textBox.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = maxLength - textBox.value.length + " " + b;
                alert('Maximum no of characters reached'); //go on with your own comment
            }
            else {
                textBox.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = maxLength - textBox.value.length + " " + b;
            }
        }
        else {
            //Below code shows how many characters left on deleting the text
            textBox.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = maxLength - textBox.value.length + " " + b;
        }
    }

    function checkSpecialKeys(e) {
        if (e.keyCode != 8 && e.keyCode != 9 && e.keyCode != 33 && e.keyCode != 34 && e.keyCode != 35 && e.keyCode != 36 && e.keyCode != 37 && e.keyCode != 38 && e.keyCode != 39 && e.keyCode != 40 && e.keyCode != 46) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Also, call JavaScript like below

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtarea" runat="server" Width="700px" Height="80px" TextMode="MultiLine"  onkeyup="multilineTextBoxKeyDown(this,event,'100')" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox>
<p style="text-align: right;">
<asp:Label ID="lblcharcnt" runat="server" Text="100"></asp:Label>
```

Code is tested now. Also, remaining number of characters will be shown on deleting the text from textbox

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps

Html:

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="yourid" runat="server" maxlength="100" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Script:

```
  $("#yourid").keyup(function ()
    {
        var a=$("#yourid").val();


        if(a.length>99)
        {
            alert("error");
        }


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It will help you, Try this,

Javascrtipt

```
    $("#textboxId").keyup(function ()
    {
            var Textboxvalue = $("#textboxId").val();


            if (Textboxvalue .length > 100)
            {
                alert("Should be 100 characters only");
            }


        });
```

Html

```
  <asp:TextBox  ID="textboxId" runat="server" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox>
```